# Constructing a nested JSON request with Jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4, jbuilder

Currently my JSON request is returning the below, where each person/`lender` has many `inventories`.

```
#output of /test.json

[
  {"id":13, "email":"johndoe@example.com", "inventories":
    [
      {"id":10,"name":"2-Person Tent","category":"Camping"},
      {"id":11,"name":"Sleeping bag","category":"Camping"},
      {"id":27,"name":"6-Person Tent","category":"Camping"}
    ]
  },

  {"id":14, "email":"janedoe@example.com", "inventories":
    [
      {"id":30,"name":"Electric drill","category":"Tools"},
      {"id":1,"name":"Hammer","category":"Tools"},
      {"id":37,"name":"Plane","category":"Tools"}
    ]
  }
]
```

I need to nest in one more thing and am having trouble doing so. For context, each `inventory` item is  referenced via it's id as a foreign key in a `borrow` record. Each `borrow` record belongs to a `request` parent that stores `returndate` and `pickupdate`. What I need now, is for each `inventory` item, to nest an array of all the `request` records, with information on `pickupdate` and `returndate`. In other words, desired output:

```
[
  {"id":13, "email":"johndoe@example.com", "inventories":
    [
      {"id":10,"name":"2-Person Tent","category":"Camping", "requests": 
        [
          {"id":1, "pickupdate":"2014-07-07","returndate":"2014-07-10"},
          {"id":2, "pickupdate":"2014-06-02","returndate":"2014-06-05"},
          {"id":3, "pickupdate":"2014-08-14","returndate":"2014-08-20"}
        ]
      },
      {"id":11,"name":"Sleeping bag","category":"Camping", "requests":
        [
          {"id":4, "pickupdate":"2014-05-27","returndate":"2014-05-30"},
          {"id":5, "pickupdate":"2014-04-22","returndate":"2014-04-25"}
        ]
      },
      {"id":27,"name":"6-Person Tent","category":"Camping", "requests":
        [
          {"id":6, "pickupdate":"2014-07-10","returndate":"2014-07-12"}
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  {"id":14, "email":"janedoe@example.com", "inventories":
  ...
```

I have written the following code:

```
json.array!(@lenders) do |json, lender|
  json.(lender, :id, :email)
  json.inventories lender.inventories do |json, inventory|
    json.id inventory.id
    json.name Itemlist.find_by_id(inventory.itemlist_id).name

    #code below says, json.requests should equal all the Requests where there is a Borrows within that Request that is using the Inventory in question
    json.requests Request.select { |r| r.borrows.select { |b| b.inventory_id == inventory.id }.present? } do |json, request|
      json.pickupdate request.pickupdate
      json.returndate request.returndate
    end
  end
end
```

When I refresh the page, I get `wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..5)`

I feel like the issue is that the `Request.select...` is returning an Array which isn't what needs to go here... but in the earlier nested function `lender.inventories` is an `Inventory::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy` though I'm not sure how to correct for this.

NOTE: Someone said the problem could be that unlike with the nesting between `inventories` and `lender`, there's not an explicit association between `inventory` and `request`, but then again the line `json.name Itemlist.find_by_id(inventory.itemlist_id).name` worked so I'm not sure this is right. (Also if this is the case, I'm not sure how to bypass this limitation... I currently don't want to create a relationship between the two.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARG. Ok so this code is perfectly right. The issue was that I"m using the Gon gem in conjunction with Jbuilder, and Request is a predefined class in Gon.

So just changed code to

```
@requestrecords.select....
```

And in the controller:

```
@requestrecords = Request.all
```

-__-